# Structured streaming: File source stream fails to start with "No usable value for path"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a file source stream that reads data from one s3 bucket and writes its results to another, like this:

```
data_sdf = spark.readStream \
    .schema(input_data.schema) \
    .parquet("s3://my_input_folder")

results_sdf = process(data_sdf)

results_query = results_sdf.writeStream \
    .format("parquet") \
    .option("path", "s3://my_results_folder") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://my_checkpoint_folder") \
    .queryName("results_query") \
    .start()
```

where `process()` is an arbitrary function for transforming a Spark DataFrame.

However after 'starting' the `results_query` stream, these statements:

```
print(spark.streams.active)
print(results_query.status)
print(results_query.lastProgress)
```

result in:

```
[]
{'message': 'Terminated with exception: No usable value for path\nDid not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String', 'isDataAvailable': False, 'isTriggerActive': False}
None
```

What I haven't said is that I have *another* structured stream that writes files to the input folder, `s3://my_input_folder`. However I still get the exception above even after stopping this other stream before trying to start the one above. But if I simply write a regular, non-streaming, DataFrame to the same input folder instead then the stream above works.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Interestingly, the Spark tutorial on structured streaming [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources) says this about file input sources:

> NOTE 2: The source path should not be used from multiple sources or queries when enabling this option. Similarly, you must ensure the source path doesn't match to any files in output directory of file stream sink.

So maybe I should *not* be trying to read files from the same folder into which I write files from another stream; and the rather cryptic error `No usable value for path` is to be expected. I guess file stream sinks don't write files atomically in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by creating new checkpoint location for target file/table instead of re-using checkpoint from earlier stream, As here we are dealing with streaming data as source.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I posted this Q some time ago and am not able to test your idea any time soon (or even confirm whether I was using the same checkpoint folder for both streams, although I suspect I might have been). If I do I'll come back and update my reply.